# How to change the default gcc/g++ include and library search path on macOS running on an apple m1 silicon

Tags: macos, boost, cmake, g++, apple-m1

I've installed the ***boost*** library using homebrew on an Apple M1 silicon running macOS Ventura (13.0)

The library and the headers got installed in the directory

```
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/boost/1.80.0/
```

and symbolic links got created in directory

`/opt/homebrew/lib/` and `/opt/homebrew/include` pointing to the aforementioned install dir.

The question is: Where I need to create symbolic links to make CMake find the boost specific resources without specifying following command in a every CMake-based C++-project?

```
link_directories("/opt/homebrew/lib")
include_directories("/opt/homebrew/include")
```

I guess, I need to find out what is the default CMake include and library search path and afterwards to create there the symbolic links.

The default include and library search path seems to be

```
`/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/include` and `/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/include`
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Wondering why cmake doesn’t find boost in your case?  We’re there any errors?

Comment: @RichardBarber yes, the headers can't be found.

Comment: I always recommended against solving this with PATH modifications.  Rather, you should add the appropriate directories to your cmake command.